# Confusion about GAE Standard env and spinning up instances in different regions

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations) for App Engine it says:

> Meeting your latency, availability, or durability requirements are
> primary factors for selecting the region where your apps are run.
>
> You cannot change an app's region after you set it.

In App Engine Standard Environment (with automatic scaling), what should I do if my application starts getting a lot of requests from a region far away from mine? For example if my region is us-east1 but I get a lot of requests from asia?

For some reason I thought that App Engine would spin up new instances in the region the request is coming from.

If wanting to build a globally accessible and fast app, this seems like a big limitation to me. Is GAE standard environment a bad choice then?

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, Google App Engine is designed for small, simple and easy to deploy server instances.

If you need global load balancing and auto scaling, then you will need to select and configure the services yourself. Google's load balancer supports global geolocation based load balancing. You can define, in advance, which regions it will load balance to. Combined with Google Compute Engine and Instance Groups, you can define the global characteristics of your site.

The tradeoff for you is how much effort do you want to spend in planning, deploying and managing your setup. Google App Engine makes this easy, but you are limited in some options. Google Compute Engine takes more effort, but you have a larger set of options to chose from and manage.

Start with some research on Google's Load Balancer to better understand the options available to you.

[GOOGLE CLOUD LOAD BALANCING](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/)